# Save the result of SHOWPLAN_ALL in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cpu

I'm working on a scalar function that returns the estimated CPU usage on a SQL query without running it. For this I am using "SHOWPLAN_ALL" with the corresponding query in a Stored Procedure that generated dynamically (varying according to the query sent).
The problem that I have is to keep the table showing the "SHOWPLAN_ALL" to use this data and get the value you want. Any idea ?
Thank you very much for the space.

Comment: I severely doubt it's possible to access the result of showplan from within T-SQL. Besides, ["SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT and SET SHOWPLAN_ALL cannot be specified inside a stored procedure; they must be the only statements in a batch."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735.aspx).